# How to start a workflow from events within a custom webpart

Tags: web-part, workflow

I would like to add workflow to my webpart. Whenever items added or removed from webparts my workflow needs to be started. I am not sure what my web part will have - it can have any items like list, asp.net controls, etc. Is this possible?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense - web parts don't 'have' lists and asp.net controls don't have workflow. Are you talking about putting a workflow on a list?

Comment: My scenario is whenever particular user edits or create any item inside web part i need to call a workflow and that workflow should decide whether particular user has permission to create or edit..am i clear..

Comment: Clear? Not really. Is the web part a custom web part or the built in ones? What is it creating - is it items in a SharePoint list or something else?

Comment: Custom web part with any type of content..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it is a webpart you have built you can manualy start and stop the workflow

here is a snippet

```
   public void StartWorkflow(SPWorkflowManager manager,string eventData,SPListItem listItem,SPWorkflowAssociation workflow)
   {
       SPWorkflowCollection workflows = manager.GetItemActiveWorkflows(listItem);
       if (workflows.Count > 0)
       {
           return;
       }
       manager.StartWorkflow(listItem, workflow, string.Empty, true);
   }
```

WorkFlow Manager Refrence
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkflowmanager_members.aspx

**EDIT:**

You will have to create the method that fires the workflow i usualy use an eventreciver of some sort. but as your question is very general i cannot give you a solution for that. but if for example you are displaying a list via a webpart. attatch an event reciver to the list and it will be kicked of if you edit it in the workflow

Comment: my web part can have any type of content..also if my web part has more than one content then i have to write event receiver for each content..

Comment: the issue is that your question is very general. but for every type of webpart you would have to code a different even reciver

Comment: ok then i have to use event receiver for every content that i use in my web part and from there i have to start my workflow..

Comment: no, its not realy about  the type of content its more about. how the content gets manipulated is it a list is their a form with a submit button etc. because depending on that you will either attach a event reciver or create a custom function. because if you look at the event reciver specs it can only attach to certin events

Comment: You shouldn't pass an empty string for the eventData parameter. You should pass an empty XML tag instead, like `<root />`.